# Derivative of Integral With Function

Tags: analysis

Let $f$ be a $C^1$ function on the line, and let $\displaystyle g(x)=\int_0^1f(xy)y^2dy.$ Prove that $g$ is a $C^1$ function and establish a formula for $g'(x)$ in terms of $f$.

I was thinking about using a change of base and replacing $xy$ with say $z.$ But then, how would the derivative $dy$ change? If we have like $z=xy,$ then $y=\frac{z}{x},$ so would $dy$ become $\frac{dz}{x}?$ And then how would the derivative and stuff change? I was thinking about using like the Libnitz rule, but I'm not sure how the derivative works anymore (also, would the integral bounds still be from $0$ to $1,$ or would that change too? Thanks

Comment: This is already the simplest change of variables to take a derivative in. Leave things as is and use chain rule.

Comment: @NinadMunshi but what does dz/x mean? Is this like (1/x)*dz? How do we derivatives with this?

Comment: How should I know? That was something you made up not me, and you have the full context of this situation.

Comment: Following your approach, since you are substituting $z=xy$, the function becomes $$ g(x)=\frac{1}{x^3}\int_{x}^{2x}z^2f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z. $$ Now you may differentiate this, using the product rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus. Note that $z$ is nothing but a dummy variable for the integral, so you don't have to worry about it. Anyway, if your ultimate goal is to show $g$ is $C^1$, actually this representation is not super convenient because you have to deal with the case $x\to 0$.

Comment: @SangchulLee can you explain how you got this?

Answer (score 1):

I will answer the original question about showing that $g$ is $C^1$.

We first predict what $g'(x)$ should look like. To this end, assume we can use Leibniz integral rule. Then

$$ g'(x)
= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int_{0}^{1} y^2 f(xy) \, \mathrm{d}y
= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} y^2 f(xy) \, \mathrm{d}y
= \int_{0}^{1} y^3 f'(xy) \, \mathrm{d}y. $$

To show that this is really the case, define

$$ h(x) = \int_{0}^{1} y^3 f'(xy) \, \mathrm{d}y. $$

We will show that $g$ is differentiable, $h$ is continuous, and $g' = h$. Fix $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $f'$ is continuous, it is uniformly continuous on the interval $I = [-|x_0|-1, |x_0| + 1]$.

**1.** Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and choose $\delta > 0$ so that

$$ \forall x, x' \in I \ : \quad |x - x'| < \delta \quad \implies \quad |f'(x) - f'(x')| < \varepsilon. $$

Then for any $x, x' \in I$ with $|x - x'| < \delta$, we have $|xy - x'y| < \delta$ for any $0 \leq y \leq 1$, and so,

$$ \left| h(x) - h(x') \right| = \int_{0}^{1} y^3 \left| f'(xy) - f'(x'y) \right| \, \mathrm{d}y
\leq \int_{0}^{1} \varepsilon y^3 \, \mathrm{d}y < \varepsilon. $$

This shows that $h$ is uniformly continuous on $I$, and in particular, continuous at $x_0$.

**2.** Again let $\varepsilon > 0$ and choose $\delta > 0$ as above. Then

\begin{align*}
\left| \frac{g(x) - g(x_0)}{x - x_0} - h(x_0) \right|
&\leq \int_{0}^{1} y^2 \left| \frac{f(xy) - f(x_0 y)}{x - x_0} - yf'(x_0 y) \right| \, \mathrm{d}y
\end{align*}

By the Mean Value Theorem, we know that

$$ \frac{f(xy) - f(x_0 y)}{x - x_0} = yf'(x^* y) $$

for some $x^*$ between $x$ and $x_0$. So, if $|x - x_0| < \delta$, then $|x^* y - x_0 y| < \delta$ for any $0 \leq y \leq 1$, hence

\begin{align*}
\left| \frac{g(x) - g(x_0)}{x - x_0} - h(x_0) \right|
&\leq \int_{0}^{1} \varepsilon y^3 \, \mathrm{d}y
< \varepsilon.
\end{align*}

This shows that $g$ is differentiable at $x_0$ with the derivative $h(x_0)$.

**Conclusion.** We have shown that $h$ defined above is continuous, $g$ is differentiable, and $g' = h$. Therefore $g$ is a $C^1$ function whose derivative is given by $h$.